# Append "/" to end of directory

Tags: unix

Completely noob question but, using ls piped to grep, I need to find files or directories that have all capitals in their name, and directories need to have "/" appended to indicate that it is a directory. Trying to append the "/" is the only part I am stuck on. Again, I apologize for the amateur question. I currently have `ls | grep [A-Z]` and the example out should be: `BIRD, DOG, DOGDIR/`

Comment: you need to include your code!  it would also help to have an example of the output you want to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interesting question because it's a somewhat difficult thing to accomplish with a bash one-liner.

Here's what I came up with.  It doesn't seem very elegant, but I'm not sure how to improve.

```
find /animals -type d -or -type f \
| grep '/[A-Z]*$' \
| xargs -I + bash -c 'echo -n $(basename +)$( test -d + && echo -n /),\\ ' \
| sed -e 's/, *$//'; echo
```

I'll break that down for you

1. `find /animals -type d -or -type f` writes out, once per line, the directories and files it found in /animals (see below for my test environment dockerfile - I created /animals to match your desired output).   Find can't do a regex match as far as I know on the name, so...
2. `grep '/[A-Z]*$'` filter's `find`'s output so that only paths are shown where the last part of the file or directory name, after the final /, is all uppercase
3. `xargs -I + bash -c '...'` when you're in a shell and you want to use a "for" loop, chances are what you should be using is `xargs`.  Learn it, know it, love it.  `xargs` takes its input, separated by default by `$IFS`, and runs the command you give it for each piece of input . So this is going to run a bash shell for each path.  that passed the grep filter.  In my case, `-I +` will make `xargs` replace the literal '+' character with its current input filename.  `-I` also makes it pass one at a time through `xargs`.  For more information, see the `xargs` manual page.
4. `'echo -n $(basename +)$( test -d + && echo -n /),\\ '` this is the inner bash script that will be run by `xargs` for each path that got through `grep`.

   1. `basename +` cuts the directory component off the path; from your example output you don't want eg `/animals/DOGDIR/`, you want `DOGDIR/`.  `basename` is the program that trims the directories for us.
   2. `test -d + && echo -n /` checks to see whether `+` (remember xargs will replace it with filename) is a directory ,and if so, runs `echo -n /`.  the `-n` argument to echo suppresses the newline, important to get the output in the CSV format you specified.

   now we can put it all together to see that we're `echo -n` the output of `basename +` , with `/` appended, if it's a directory, and then `,` appended to that.  All the `echo`s run with `-n` to suppress newlines to keep output CSV looking.
5. `| sed -e 's/, *$//'; echo` is purely for formatting.  Adding `,` to each individual output was an easy way to get the CSV, but it leaves us with a final `,` at the end of the list.  The `sed` invocation removes `,` followed by any number of spaces at the end of the output so far  - eg the entire output from all the xargs invocations.  And since we never did output a newline at the end of that output, the final `echo` is adding that.

Usually in unix shells, you probably wouldn't want a CSV style output.  You'd probably instead want a newline-separated output in most cases, one matching file per line, and that would be somewhat simpler to do because you wouldn't need all that faffing with `-n` and `,` to make it CSV style.  But, valid requirement if the need is there.

```
FROM debian
RUN mkdir -p /animals
WORKDIR /animals
RUN mkdir -p DOGDIR lowerdir && touch DOGDIR/DOG DOGDIR/lowerDOG2 lowerdir/BIRD
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]
CMD [ "-c" , "find /animals -type d -or -type f | grep '/[A-Z]*$'| xargs -I + bash -c 'echo -n $(basename +)$( test -d + && echo -n /),\\ ' | sed -e 's/, *$//'; echo"]
```

```sh
$ docker run --rm test
BIRD, DOGDIR/, DOG
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start looking at

```
ls -F | grep -v "[[:lower:]]"
```

I did not add something for a comma-seperated line, because this is the wrong method: Parsing `ls` should be avoided ! It will go wrong for filenames like

```
I am a terribble filename,
with newlines inside me,
and the ls command combined with grep
will only show the last line
BECAUSE THIS LINE HAS NO LOWERCASE CHARACTERS
```

To get the files without a pipe, you can use

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -dp +([[:upper:]])
shopt -u extglob
```

An explanation of the extglob and uppercase can be found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389071/57293

When you want the output in one line, you can get troubles with filenames that have newlines or commas in its name. You might want something like

```
# parsing ls, yes wrong and failing for some files
ls -dp +([[:upper:]]) | tr "\n" "," | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```